# Error configuring Spring data and neo4j embedded

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data

I'm building a POC with Spring Data and Neo4j embedded, i've followed the configuration tutorial on Spring Data documentation, but when i try to run the project, i get an "Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource".

I tried some different configurations on my applicationContext.xml and some different versions of Spring Data and Neo4j dependencies, without success neither, just different errors. What is wrong?

Here is my applicationContext.xml, pom.xml and the stacktrace:

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
        destroy-method="shutdown">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="data/graph.db" />
        <constructor-arg index="1">
            <map>
                <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true" />
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="serverWrapper" class="org.neo4j.server.WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper"
        init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
        <constructor-arg ref="graphDatabaseService" />
    </bean>



    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.teste" />

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Spring Data Neo4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-M01</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
        <classifier>static-web</classifier>
        <version>2.1.0-M01</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Apache Commons Lang -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
       <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
       <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- JSON Resolver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId> org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>   
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>
      <repository>
            <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
     </repository>
     <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Springframework Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>

 <build>
    <finalName>teste-spring</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- NB: You must use Maven 2.0.9 or above or these are ignored (see MNG-2972) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <outxml>true</outxml>
            <aspectLibraries>
                <aspectLibrary>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                </aspectLibrary>
                <aspectLibrary>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-aspects</artifactId>
                </aspectLibrary>
            </aspectLibraries>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>    
  </build>
</project>
```

stacktrace

```
Mar 26, 2014 11:39:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config]: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Config]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [java.lang.Iterable]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:716)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Related cause:
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphDatabaseService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [java.lang.Iterable]: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:727)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Does it work with the latest Neo4j stable release (2.0.1)? They seem to have added a second constructor in the milestone release, so that could have caused the ambiguity.

Comment: No, i've tried Neo4j 2.0.1 and the milestone with actual(3.0.1) and previous release(2.3.5) of Spring Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` class is deprecated (it will be hidden in a future release), it's a good practice to already avoid it. The best way to build a `GraphDatabaseSerice`, is by using the `GraphDatabaseFactory` and in your case the related `GraphDatabaseBuilder`. If you'd configure your Spring beans in java, this is what it could look like:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("applicationContext.xml")
class SpringConfiguration extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("db")
            .setConfig("enable_remote_shell", "true").newGraphDatabase();
    }
}
```

I realize that the `setConfig` method I'm using is deprecated as well, but I don't see an equivalent in the `GraphDatabaseSettings` class.

If you want to use this approach, you'll have to use a `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` in your web.xml.

If you wish to continue with XML configuration, there' a convenience bean:

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
        destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg value="db"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="enable_remote_shell" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I've saw this blog post, and tried this example, but then i got a different error: "Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: data/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)", wich doesn't makes sense, the database directory is created during runtime, so there is no other processes using it and there is fully permission to write the directory and its files

Comment: See updated post as well. The exception you're getting is probably related to the `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper`. Is it referring to the same `graphDatabaseService`?

Comment: Also, use the `WrappingNeoServer` class, instead of `WrappingNeoServerBootstrapper`.

Comment: I was having some trouble, but it was the javax.validation dependency, i just remove it and worked well. Thanks a lot man.